# Let $\zeta=\{E \in \mathcal{P}(X): card(E)=2 \}$ proof that $\sigma(\zeta)=\mu_{c}$

Tags: measure-theory

Consider $X$ an uncountable set and $\mu_{c}:=\{A\in \mathcal{P}(X): A\quad\text{is countable or} \quad X-{A}\quad \text{is countable} \}$

Let $\zeta=\{E \in \mathcal{P}(X): card(E)=2 \}$

proof that $\sigma(\zeta)=\mu_{c}$

it is clear that $\mu_{c}$ is a sigma-algebra that contains $\zeta$, indeed, given $E\in \zeta$ then $Card(E)$=2 so, $E$ is countable and therefore $E \in \mu_{c}$  and we know that $\sigma (\zeta)$ is the smallest sigma algebra that contains $\zeta$,

therefore, $\sigma (\zeta) \subset \mu_{c} $

for the other contention I expressed $\sigma(\zeta)$ as follows:

$\sigma(\zeta)= \bigcap_{g \in G} g$, $G$ is the set of all sigma algebras that contain $\zeta$

then, to prove that $\mu_{c} \subset \sigma (\zeta)$ take a $s\in \mu_{c}$ and $g\in G$ But I have not been able to find a good reasoning that leads me to show that $s \in g$

Comment: Can you precise what $\sigma$ means is here?

Comment: It is the sigma algebra generated by $ \zeta $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We actually have $\sigma(\zeta) = \mu_c$ whenever $|X| \neq 2$. It's just less interesting when $X$ isn't uncountable.  The case of $|X|=1$ is trivial (there's only one $\sigma$-algebra), so I'll assume $|X|\geq 3$ here.

First note, as you've done, that $\zeta \subseteq \mu_c,$ so as $\mu_c$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, $\sigma(\zeta) \subseteq \mu_c.$

For the other direction, let $x \in X$.  Since $|X| \geq 3$, there are at least two other distinct points $y,z \in X,$ so that $\{x,y\}, \{x,z\} \in \zeta$.  Therefore, $$\{x\} = \{x,y\} \cap \{x,z\} \in \sigma(\zeta),$$ so for any $x\in X$, we have $\{x\} \in \sigma(\zeta)$.

Now let $A\in \mu_c$, so by cases, either

- $A \subseteq X$ is countable: Then $A = \bigcup_{x\in A} \{x\} \in \sigma(\zeta),$ as it's a countable union of elements of $\sigma(\zeta).$
- $X-A \subseteq X$ is countable: Then $X-A \in \sigma(\zeta)$ as in the previous case and then $A = X-(X-A) \in \sigma(\zeta)$.

It follows that $\mu_c \subseteq \sigma(\zeta)$.

Answer (score 1):

If $A\in\mu_c$ is countable, let $\{P_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ be a partition of $A$ into $2$-element sets; then $P_n\in\zeta$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$, so $A=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}P_n\in\sigma(\zeta)$.

For that matter, we could simply let $\mathscr{P}$ be the family of all $2$-element subsets of $A$: $A$ is countable, so $\mathscr{P}$ is also countable, and $A=\bigcup\mathscr{P}\in\sigma(\zeta)$.

Thus, every countable member of $\mu_c$ belongs to $\sigma(\zeta)$, and $\sigma(\zeta)$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, so it must contain the complements of these sets as well. It follows that $\mu_c\subseteq\sigma(\zeta)$ and hence that $\mu_c=\sigma(\zeta)$.